# Error with my code? (cycle in linked list)

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm currently relearning some of my old previous knowledge in data structures, and decided to work on problems such as HackerRank. I came across an easy question where we have to detect a cycle in a linked list, but I can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong. I have looked at other answers, and understood their syntax and logic, but can't seem to find the logic in which my code fails.

```
boolean hasCycle(Node head) {

    if (head == null || head.next == null){
        return false;
    }

    Node first = head;
    Node second = head.next;

    while (second != null){
        if (first == second)
        {
            return true;
        }
        first = first.next;
        second = second.next.next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by cycle?

Comment: Instead of a circular linked list, where the initial "tail" node points to the head, I'm checking the full linked list to see if it's circular.  If it does have a cycle, it can be where one node points back to another previous node. Heres the problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-linked-list-cycle

Comment: This program is small enough that you can step through it line by line in the debugger.

Comment: What is the error message? Your code kind of lacks the main method and the Node class. Looks like you choose the java challenge?

Comment: Besides your list may have a maximum length of 100 as it says in your link. You might want to use that to your advantage. ;)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it your list can have a circle in any of the nodes, not just the first. Your code is far from the solution. 
You can simplify how you think of the problem as having to check if a node is visited more than once.
To do this you can use a helper function like this

```
boolean visitedMoreThanOnce(Node head)
{
   if (head.next == null){
        return false;
    }


    Node second = head.next;

    while (second != null){
        if (head == second)
        {
            return true;
        }
        second = second.next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then your function could be

```
boolean hasCycle(Node head) {

Node first = head;
while (first != null){
    if (visitedMoreThanOnce(first))
    {
        return true;
    }
    first = first.next;
}
return false;
}
```

Note that I solved it with your function signature. By looking at the problem in the link provided in the comments in your question, it seams that head should be a pointer. In that case you will need to use `->` operator, instead of `.`

Comment: I think this would be called cheating on hackerrank, since if you can use a helper, why not use the helper hasCycle(head)? :D - the list has a max length of 100 as it says on https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-linked-list-cycle

Comment: I wrote the code for the helper. I dont know the hackerrank rules but he can put the code i put in the helper function inside the while loop. It is the same thing. Just more readable the way I did it.

Comment: Ah OK there it is. =) - you want to do something about the lists max size of 100?